# Revolution slider with php (laravel)

Tags: revolution-slider

I want to use Revolution Slider within my html template.
Main issue is I have no any idea how to integrate it to my database and PHP codes.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The core concept of visual editor is to use it as standalone slider builder tool which spits out a full html code with all links, markups etc without the needs to understand html/css/slider functions at all for your sliders. And have ability to export it in html or include it using php functions.

Full integration include user authorization, fixing possible code conflicts, other possible caveats.

The most easiest way to integrate is to add an option to specify slider alias and pass it to render functions. And keep editor as separate application.

If you add more details about how exactly you want to integrate it i would try to give you better answer.

Comment: http://thememascot.net/demo/personal/s/studypress/v6.0/demo/index-mp-layout2.html
I just purchased for this theme and want to integrate revolution slider dynamically that the default animations can be changeable by admin, and it is complicated for me how it can be made and how will database structure be